# Как найти число в массиве без пары?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

У меня есть массив:

```
[1, 3, 3, 1, 8, 9, 9]
```

где числа парные, две единицы, две тройки и так далее.

Вопрос: может так оказаться что будет массив в котором у одного числа не будет пары, как узнать это число (в моем примере это 8) **наиболее оптимальным и коротким вариантом**?

Может есть какой-то метод у массива о котором я не знаю который может это сделать за одну строчку вместо двух или трех циклов?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, в данной ситуации, самым оптимальным вариантом будет воспользоваться [bitwise-оператором XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR_assignment):

```js
const array = [1, 3, 3, 1, 8, 9, 9]

const result = array.reduce((acc, cur) => acc ^ cur, 0)

console.log(result)
// 8
```